# Creating a dummy progress bar

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a dummy progress bar that is initiated when the user clicks the submit button, and then disappears when the data is returned.

I would like it to load a little bit to a certain point to show the user that the data is being returned, and then complete once the data is rendered.

Any advice on how I could achieve this?

Here is my bootstrap progress bar template:

```
<div id="loadingcontainer">
<div class="progress" style="height: 5px;">
    <div id="myprogress" class="progress-bar" style="color:#EB7051;" style="background-color: #ffffff" role="progressbar" style="width: 25%;" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my script tag:

```
    function searchIt() {

        let form = document.querySelector('form')
        console.log(form)

        form.addEventListener('submit', async(e) => {
            e.preventDefault()
            let urlIN = form.url.value
            let url = encodeURIComponent(urlIN)
            console.log(url)
            try {
                const data = await fetch('/', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        url: url
                    })

                }).then(res => {
                    document.open()
                    res.text().then(function(text) {

                        document.write(text)
                
                    });

                })


            } catch (err) {
                console.error(err)
            }

        })
```

[image]

Comment: Can you show the progress bar code you have tried? - Stack Overflow isn't actually a free code writing service.

Comment: @traktor I added what I am hoping to render

Comment: I have tried way too many things to only post 1